# Add private method in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, methods, private

I'm trying to make a basic game to strengthen my JavaScript knowledge. But I need some help with trying to add private methods to an object. The reason for this is that I want to the user to be able to access certain moves once they reach a certain condition, but not before. I also don't want to have to add the methods each time the character levels up. Here is some code:

```
function Character(name, type, sex) {
    this.name = name;
    this.type = type;
    this.sex = sex;
    //Ignore this part as well this.punch = function() {
        //Ignore this. Will work on later
    }
};

var rock = new Character('Stoner', 'Rock', 'Male');
```

Comment: regardless of the commands visibility, it's the UI that should provide access (or not) to such a feature, unless you expect folks to rewrite the js code themselves...

Comment: Oh I forgot to add that there won't be any GUI as this will be very simple (just finished the JS course in codecademy)

Comment: well, in the constructor you could do: `Object.defineProperty(this, "punch", {get:function(){return this.type=='master' ? punch : Boolean }});`, using a private punch function or a boolean if the condition is not met yet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I don't think this is what the OP is looking for... It seems like the OP wants them "private" until the user hits a certain level and then public

Assuming this comment is right...

It doesn't need to be a private method, have it be a public method and then use an if/else statement to handle if they don't have enough "levels".

```
function Character(name, type, sex) {
  this.name = name;
  this.type = type;
  this.sex = sex;

  this.level = 10;

  this.punch = (function(){
    if (this.level > 5) {
      /* Punch functionality goes here. */
    } else {
      /* They don't have enough levels, tell them that! */
    }
  }).bind(this)
}
```

I'm only assuming you're using levels.  If you have some other system, you can simply adapt it.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of this.punch if you use "var" it will become private.

```
 function Character(name, type, sex) {
        this.name = name;
        this.type = type;
        this.sex = sex;
        var punch = function() {
            //Ignore this. Will work on later
        }

    };

    var rock = new Character('Stoner', 'Rock', 'Male');
```

Comment: I don't think this is what the OP is looking for... It seems like the OP wants them "private" until the user hits a certain level and then public.

Comment: Yeah the punch method was meant to be public

Comment: In that case we can provide a public method whose job would be checking the level and accordingly return the private method pouch. Just a suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

This is a total guess, but this is my opinion based on what it *seems* like you want. I can't think of another way at the moment.

```
function Character(name, type, sex) {
    var level = 1;
    this.name = name;
    this.type = type;
    this.sex = sex;
    this.punch = function() {
        // If the user isn't over level 5, don't punch anything
        if (level < 5) {
            return;
        }
        // Punch something
    }
}
```

Obviously you will need some way of leveling the character up...